# Hangman game. How to slice strings to change original value

Tags: python, string

I am very new to python and I am attempting to make a hangman game.
I would like to change a string to show the number of guessed letters but for some reason I keep on getting weird results. Here is my code:

```
import random
guesses_left = 9 
def show_guesses_left():
    print("You have", guesses_left, "guesses left")


wordlist = ['nerd', 'python', 'great', 'happy', 'programmer', 'long', 'short', 'stupid']
word = random.choice(wordlist)
wordwin = word
hidden_word = ["?" for q in word]
letters_guessed = ''.join(hidden_word)

print("Welcome to Hangman!!")
print("My word is", len(word), "letters long")
print(wordwin)
print(letters_guessed)


def request_guess():
    global guesses_left
    global word
    global letters_guessed
    x = input(f"What is your guess? \n{letters_guessed}")

    if x in word:
        print("Great you guessed a letter")
        t = word.find(x)
        word = word.replace(x, "")
        print(t)
        letters_guessed = letters_guessed[:t] + letters_guessed[t:t+1].replace('?', x) + letters_guessed[t+1:]


    elif type(x) is not str or len(x) > 1:
        print("Invalid guess, Your guess must be 1 letter long")
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
        guesses_left -= 1
        show_guesses_left()



def start_game():
    global letters_guessed
    global word
    global guesses_left
    letters_guessed = ''.join(hidden_word)
    while True:
        if guesses_left > 0 and len(word) != 0:
            request_guess()


        elif len(word) == 0:
            print(f"YOU WIN!!!, the word was {wordwin}")
            break

        else:
            print("You lose! Better luck next time!")
            break
start_game()
```

I keep on getting this result where it only works for the for some letters and the placing is wrong. Here is my result:

```
Welcome to Hangman!!
My word is 4 letters long
long
????
What is your guess? 
????l
Great you guessed a letter
0
What is your guess? 
l???n
Great you guessed a letter
1
What is your guess? 
ln??o
Great you guessed a letter
0
What is your guess? 
ln??g
Great you guessed a letter
0
YOU WIN!!!, the word was long
```

Why cant i just slice the string change one character and slice the rest?
Why does it work the first time and not the second?
If anybody can explain to me what is going on it would be appreciated

Comment: You will want to update your hidden word, and not letters guessed.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are basing that splicing on a variable that you modify on the go. In particular, the variable `word`, where you look for the position of `x`, the guessed letter. The position is correct until `word` gets modified in length, as you replace the letter with an empty string.

An easy fix for that is to simply change the replace statement, and put either an empty space, or another character, that the user would not normally put. In my example, I would replace:

```
word = word.replace(x, "")
```

with

```
word = word.replace(x, " ")
```

That of course breaks the program exit logic: you can never win.

There is still another issue, that is multiple occurrences of the same letter are not accounted properly. In fact, the program loops until exhaustion, when multiple instances of the same letter are in `word`.

That is due to the fact that `find` will only reveal the position of the **first** instance of a given letter, and you don't account for possible duplicates.

There are several ways to fix that, but I think the main issue is identified.

For an alternate implementation, check https://eval.in/1051220

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
import random
guesses_left = 9
def show_guesses_left():
    print("You have", guesses_left, "guesses left")


wordlist = ['nerd', 'python', 'great', 'long', 'short', 'stupid', 'happy', 'programmer']
word = random.choice(wordlist)
wordwin = list(word)
hidden_word = list('?' * len(word))
letters_guessed = ''.join(hidden_word)

print("Welcome to Hangman!!")
print("My word is", len(word), "letters long")
print(letters_guessed)


def request_guess():
    global guesses_left
    global word
    global letters_guessed
    x = input("\nWhat is your guess?\n" + letters_guessed + "\n")

    if x in word:
        print("\nGreat you guessed a letter")
        for i, j in enumerate(word):
            if j == x:
                hidden_word[i] = j
        letters_guessed = ''.join(hidden_word)

        print(letters_guessed + "\n")
    elif type(x) is not str or len(x) > 1:
        print("Invalid guess, Your guess must be 1 letter long")
    else:
        print("\nWrong!")
        guesses_left -= 1
        show_guesses_left()



def start_game():
    global letters_guessed
    global word
    global guesses_left
    letters_guessed = ''.join(hidden_word)
    while True:
        if guesses_left > 0 and letters_guessed != word:
            request_guess()
        elif letters_guessed == word:
            print("YOU WIN!!!, the word was " + word)
            break

        else:
            print("\nYou lose! Better luck next time!")
            break
start_game()
```

**Notes**

Got it to work!
Sorry short on time will be back to help more, but take a look around. I used some different methods than you originally had, seems like there was a issue with your `letters_guessed` not revealing letters past a letter already guessed. This will work for double letters as well, which also seemed to be an issued with your original code.

Again sorry, will be back to explain more!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the code you use to get the index of the guessed letter:

```
    t = word.find(x)
    word = word.replace(x, "")
```

This shortens `word` after each correct guess, so `t` will not be the desired value after the first correct guess.

However, even if you fix this, you will still not properly handle the case that the guessed letter occurs multiple times.

Here is a short example that shows how to solve both problems:

```
answer = 'long'
hidden = '?' * len(answer)
print("Welcome to hangman!")
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    result = ''
    if guess in answer:
        for answer_letter, hidden_letter in zip(answer, hidden):
            if guess == answer_letter:
                result += guess
            else:
                result += hidden_letter
        hidden = result
    print(hidden)
    if hidden == answer:
        print("You guessed it!")
        break
```